# Manage.py unknown command

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am a student and my profesor needs me to install Django on PyCharm.

I made a big folder called PyCharmProjects and it includes like everything I have done in Python.

The problem is that I made a new folder inside this PyCharmProjects called Elementar, and I need to have the Django folders in there but it's not downloading.

I type in the PyCharm terminal django-admin manage.py startproject taskmanager1 (this is how my profesor needs me to name it)

After I run the code it says:

No Django settings specified.
Unknown command: 'manage.py'
Type 'django-admin help' for usage.

I also tried to install it through the MacOS terminal but I don't even have acces the folder named Elementar (cd: no such file or directory: Elementar) although it is created and it is seen in the PyCharm.

Comment: It should only be `django-admin startproject taskmanager1`, there is no need to include `manage.py` in this command.

Answer (score 1):

Manage.py its python file after you start your project, you cant call this file until this command:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Then run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And if you want apps in your project run:

```
python manage.py startapp my_app
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't create a project using manage.py because the manage.py file doesn't exist yet. It will be created automatically in the folder taskmanager1 if you run the command below.

You can create a project with the command
`django-admin startproject taskmanager1`

After that you can change the directory to the `taskmanager1` folder with the `cd taskmanager/` command.

When you changed the directory you can use the python manage.py commando for example if you want to run your migrations or creating an app.
`python manage.py migrate`